# Workaround for Opacity + Magnify bug in version 12?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, polygons, opacity

Is there a workaround for the following bug in version 12.0.0. This is in MacOSX.

```
g = Graphics3D[{}, ImageSize -> {1000, Automatic}, Boxed -> False,       ViewPoint -> 10^3 {1, 1.45, .5}, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}];
g = Show[g, Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[.5], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}]];
Magnify[g, .5]
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: works fine on Mathematica 12 / Ubuntu 18.4. Maybe try the option "ImageSize -> 500" inside Show[...] instead of Magnify.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on macOS 10.14 with Mathematica 12.0.0 and a Radeon Pro 560 GPU

Comment: What if you go to your Option Inspector, change Scope to Global Preferences, and change the value for Graphics Options -> Rendering Options -> 3D Rendering Engine to some of the other values? Do any of those help?